# Problema en Java! (impresion de un valor retornado dentro de un if)

Tags: java

resulta que tengo cierto problema a la hora de seguir con mi código el cual encima es una tarea de la u, yo normalmente utilizo es Javascript, y soy nuevo en esto de Java, por lo cual no se muchas cosas básicas, pero teniendo experiencia programando en otro lenguaje como lo es Javascript, pensé que usando mas o menos la misma lógica que utilizo en Javascript para hacer mis proyectos podría usarse en Java, pues resulta que al parecer no...

El problema resumidamente es el siguiente:

Tengo una función aparte llamada binarioAInt, la cual retorna un valor.
tengo luego debajo de esa función (Afuera de la función binarioAInt) mi función principal, (La que contiene String[] args) llamada main, resulta que todo va de maravilla cuando yo la uso con sus respectivos parámetros en el main, y entonces una vez ejecutada la función binarioAInt con sus respectivos parametros imprimo el valor que es generado, cuando lo hago así todo va perfecto me da el valor correcto y todo, pero...

si hago algo tan simple como poner la linea de código donde voy a imprimir tal valor retornado dentro de un if, no me imprime nada!, y eso que comprobé que de verdad se estuviera entrando al if, y aun no me explico por que no funciona...

¿alguna idea?

aquí el código:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class Conversor_Binario {

    public static int binarioAInt(String binario,int[] limits,String[] arrBinario) {

        int numAS = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int n = 1;

        for(int i = arrBinario.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {

            if(i == arrBinario.length-1) {

                n = 1;

            }else {

                n = n*2;

            }

            limits[i] = n;

        }

        while(j < binario.length()) {

            arrBinario[j] = binario.substring(j,j+1);

            j++;

        }

        for(int k = 0; k < arrBinario.length ; k++) {

            if(arrBinario[k].indexOf("1") != -1) {

                numAS = numAS + limits[k];

            }

        }

        return numAS;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintStream imprimir = System.out;
        Scanner escanear = new Scanner(System.in);
        String typeConversion;
        String mayuscTypeConversion;

        String entradaUsuario;

        imprimir.print("¡Bienvenido al conversor binario!, escribe un numero en binario o decimal y lo convertiremos a");
        imprimir.print(" su correspondiente equivalente.");
        imprimir.println("");
        imprimir.println("");
        imprimir.print("¿Qué deseas convertir?, escribe D (para convertir de decimal a binario), escribe B (para convertir");
        imprimir.print(" de binario a decimal).");
        imprimir.println("");
        imprimir.println("");

        typeConversion = escanear.nextLine();
        mayuscTypeConversion = typeConversion.toUpperCase();

        imprimir.println("");
        imprimir.println("Ahora dame el valor a convertir:");
        imprimir.println("");

        entradaUsuario = escanear.nextLine();
        String[] arregloBinario = new String[entradaUsuario.length()];

        imprimir.println("");

        int[] limites = new int[entradaUsuario.length()];
        //Aquí en este condicional esta el problema... si dejas el contenido fuera del condicional si funciona correctamente.
        if(mayuscTypeConversion == "B") {

            imprimir.println(binarioAInt(entradaUsuario,limites,arregloBinario));

        }

        escanear.close();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es simple, no debes usar el operador `==` para comparar cadenas, debes usar el método **[equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)**.

Para realizar la conversión de Integer a Binario lo puedes realizar mediante el método:

**[Integer.toBinaryString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString)**

Este sería el código :

```
if(mayuscTypeConversion.equals("B")) {

    imprimir.println(binarioAInt(entradaUsuario,limites,arregloBinario));

}else if(mayuscTypeConversion.equals("D")){

    imprimir.println(Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(entradaUsuario)));

}else{
    imprimir.println("No selecciono formato de conversión.");
}
```

Lo que sucedía es que en realidad nunca entraba a realizar la impresión del valor.

Comment: Muchas gracias!, fue de utilidad saber esto, no sabia que en java no podías hacer lo del == que se hace en javascript con las cadenas...

Comment: Un placer ayudarte @Riven , agregué la forma de convertir de decimal a binario, saludos!